# How To Use django.views.APIView In Python?

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

I'm currently facing trouble using rest_framework.views.APIView. When I try running python manage.py makemigrations, it says that there is nthroughing such as django.utils.six. The line that it throws an error on is from rest_framework.views import APIView. Can anyone give me guidance on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you use `django-jsonfield`?

Comment: Hi, No I'm not using django-jsonfield.

Comment: are you running django 2 because django.utils.six is removed in django 3 https://medium.com/@vdboor/patching-a-missing-django-utils-six-f882f93ccbce

Comment: No, I'm running django v3.1.3. But, I'm also running djangorestframework v3.12.2. Do I have to upgrade djangorestframework to 3.9 to fix the issue?